# my code in c++. Will there be a memory leak?

Tags: c++

```
int * myArr(int num) {
    static int *Arr = new int[num];
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < num; i++) {
        *(Arr + i) = i;
        std::cout << *(Arr + i) << "\n";
    }
    //delete[] Arr;
    return Arr;
}

int main()
{
    int *testArr = myArr(4);
    for (int i{ 0 }; i < 4; i++) {
        std::cout << *(testArr + i) << "\n";
    }
    delete[] testArr;
}
```

is there a memory leak if i try to delete[] testArr inside main() instead of delete[] Arr in the myArr function? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: testArr will point to the same object as Arr within the function. Hence freeing testArr is correct. Would you free Arr before returning it, your testArr would point into nowhere (and your software will crash just after passing some tests).

Comment: No memory leak, but you should never call `myArr` again after the `delete[]`.

Comment: `static int *Arr = new int[num];` - why `static`?

Comment: @PaulSanders : ah, i want that expression to execute 1 time for the first time the myArr func is called, but the next time i dont want the program to dynamic allocate different memory for that array again. Im a beginner, sometime i dont know exactly what iam doing or what i should do.

Comment: @mch : i try to call the func myArr the second time after delete[] testArr; and it still work.

Comment: @Ronald: thanks for your reply, good to know at least no memory leak.

Comment: @TuanPham (your response to my comment) That would be poor strategy - it's just an open invitation for things to go wrong.  And 'still works' when you call `myArr` a second time is pure fluke.  You're writing to memory you no longer own.

Comment: @PaulSanders : Yes a poor Strategy, i keep the static keyword and call the function second time, it crash. If i delete the static then the program run. Thanks!!!

Comment: @PaulSanders What do you mean by `You're writing to memory you no longer own.` As long as the `delete[]` on this memory (via `Arr` or `testArr`), is not called, any reference to that memory (again via `Arr` or `testArr` or possibly via another `int* abcdef = testArr`) is well-defined behaviour, no?

Comment: @Tryer Well I guess it depends on the pattern of calls to `myArr` and `delete`, but that `static` is fraught with danger in any event.  Suppose you pass a different (larger) value in `num` in  the second call to `myArr`?  `myArr` will then write past the end of the original allocation since no new allocation is made.

Comment: @PaulSanders I agree with your example. However, the way the code in the OP is currently structured, there is no need to call the function a 2nd time. (no state changes as far as I can see). From within main, a new call to the function as `int* testArr2 = myArr(4);` is no different from simply saying `int* testArr2 = testArr;` I only wanted to point out that as long as every subsequent call to this function is with an argument that is no greater than the first call, `4` in the OP's example, the code is well defined. Your example would violate this since you are calling with a greater argument.

Comment: @Tryer With all due respect, you're missing the point.  `myArr` is fundamentally flawed and it's important that the OP (who is inexperienced) sees that.  Please don't muddy the waters by arguing about things that really don't matter, it's not helpful.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but `*(testArr + i)` should be written `testArr[i]`. The two mean exactly the same thing, but the second is idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

> Will there be a memory leak?

There is no leak in the example.

> if i try to delete[] testArr inside main() instead of delete[] Arr in the myArr function?

If you did that, then attempting to access the array in `main` would result in undefined behaviour. Don't do that.

---

P.S. Don't use bare owning pointers. Use `std::vector` instead. Example:

```
std::vector<int> myArr(int num) {
    auto iota = std::ranges::iota_view{0, num};
    return std::vector<int>(iota.begin(), iota.end());
}
```

Comment: im trying to write a function that take 1 parameter and use it as the inside array lenth then return the array through pointer. This is the only way i found while googling. I will try std::vector as well. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @TuanPham I added an example.